# Android Code decoding

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm a beginner in Android programming.So i'm going through some Sample Projects and Blogs.I came up on this code , which i want to know why is it used ?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        InterpolatorFragment fragment = new InterpolatorFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: see this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: but what do the .replace() and .commit() do exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);

This tells that in **sample_content_fragment** `FrameLayout`  remove the current displaying fragment and show new fragment **fragment** (second parameter)

> transaction.commit();

This tells that everything is done with fragment and this is right time to replace the fragment

for more details see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: Thanks ! I followed that link . It is nice !